# Is there a numerical overview over your XP progression?

Tags: borderlands-2

In Borderlands 2, you always have the XP bar and your current level right at the bottom of your screen. However, there's no numerical indication of my total amount of XP earned, XP needed for the next level and so on. I have checked all the ingame menues but can't seem to find any information/overview screen with this information. Is there an (ingame) way to see numerical values for your XP progression?

I know I can look up the amount of XP needed per level online, but I would like to know if it's shown anywhere ingame as well. The reason I'm asking is because since there's no indication about how much XP is needed for the next level, I have no idea how much any amount of XP I get from kills and missions is 'worth'. So is there anything I have overlooked?

Comment: I thought there was in the menu?

Comment: @TimmyJim I didn't find it, but maybe I'm blind. Feel free to point it out in an answer and I will gladly accept it!

Comment: @MoritzLost I'm finding an in-game screenshot right now to provide an answer.

Comment: @Despato Ok I found it right now. Now I feel dumb. Anyway, feel free to answer the question in case anyone else is blind like me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Borderlands 2, it is possible to view your experience in 2 places. The first is the large EXP bar that is at the very bottom of the HUD:

[image: EXP Bar]

The other place to view your experience, and also the only place that will display the exact numerical amount, is on the left-most menu page, shown here:

[image: Missions page displaying EXP value]

The experience is represented as:

> Total Experience Earned / Total Experience to Next Level

Answer (score 6):

Its under the My Missions tab, at the bottom.  See this screenshot:

[image: Xp amount]